# How to share authentication between Parent and Sub project?

Tags: authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to develop an application which will contain one Parent project and multiple child projects (Sub projects). But I want to share authentication between them i.e. If a person has logged in during his session with Parent project, Sub project should be able to get this information (That user is already logged in).

Can someone please help me out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a "core" project which will hold all base functionality (Authentication, Access Control, base utilities, ...). Then each sub-project depends on the core-project, and by means of dependency, the parent project will also know about the core. [This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ManuelBernhardt/tips-and-tricks-for-setting-up-a-play-2-project) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using play.mvc.Security annotation and using my own implementation of security authenticator in it. Below is the annotation used in entry controller of sub projects:

```
@Security.Authenticated(SecuredLogin.class)
```

SecuredLogin.java is the file which checks whether session has a user in it, if yes, then performs some Sub Project specific functions like getting role of the user from web service. i.e.

```
public class SecuredLogin extends Security.Authenticator {

@Override
public String getLoggedInUsername(Context ctx) {
    if (Controller.session("LOGGEDIN_USERNAME") != null){
        return ctx.session().get("LOGGEDIN_USERID");
    } else {
        String devResidingUser = Controller.session().get("RESIDING_USER");
        UserRoleInformation userRoleInfo ;
        try {
            userRoleInfo = DataController.retrieveUserRoleInformation(devResidingUser);
           Controller.session().put("LOGGEDIN_USERNAME", devResidingUser);
           ctx.session().put("LOGGEDIN_USERROLE", userRoleInfo);
           ctx.session().put("LOGGEDIN_USERID", userRoleInfo.getUserId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Controller.session().put("SERVER_ERROR", "TRUE");
            return null;
        }
        ctx.session().put("USERNAME", devResidingUser);
        return devResidingUser;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks everybody for devoting your time in solving this.